# Meaning and usage of "Das Gericht muss sich mit dem Fall beschäftigen"

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context, idiom

I read this example sentence in Duden:

> Das Gericht muss sich mit dem Fall beschäftigen.

I am wondering whether this is a formula used in court of law when the judge makes such announcements as "The court is adjourned."?

Comment: I don't think it's a formula in court, but can you give a little bit more context to assess your question?

Comment: @IQV unfortunately Duden Dictionary does not reveal any context, that is why i am trying to figure out some appropriate context for this example sentence

Comment: "The court has to take care the case". Your this question is a dupe of your previous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't a formula, legal or otherwise. It's simply a free combination of words that means exactly what you would expect. And it doesn't sound like something a judge would say either; it sounds like something a reporter would write about a dispute *as it being escalated to a legal dispute*, i.e. *before* it goes to court.

Comment: Lynnyo expected that this sentence would mean »The court is adjourned.« (to adjourn = vertagen), but this is wrong, and so you answer is wrong too.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: No, he or she didn't expect that. "The court is adjourned." was presented as an example for a set phrase used by judges, whose content is, however, not equivalent to the meaning of "Das Gericht muss sich mit dem Fall beschäftigen."

Answer (score 1):

This is just a normal sentence. No formula and no idiomatic expression. It means:

> The court has to deal with the case.

Your suggestion "*The court is adjourned*" is wrong. A court can only adjourn a case that is has opened before. This is not what the sentence above really means. It means:

> The court has to open a new case. The court has not dealt with this case before. There already is an dispute, but the court was not involved into this dispute until now. But in the future the court has to deal with it.